# How to set a field into UNIQUE in play framework?

Tags: java, mysql, playframework

For example, I want to set noticeTitle into UNIQUE field in database.BTW,I use mysql in my project.I want `noticeTitle` irreproducible. I'd like it be `UNIQUE` filed in mysql. So how could I do that?

```
@Entity
public class Notice extends Model {
    public String noticeTitle; 
    public DateTime createTime; 
    public String content; 
}
```

Comment: 'Set a field into duplicate' / 'set noticeTitle into no duplicate' - can you explain this some more? Are you looking for help on defining a primary key column that is unique? In which case you might be looking for the @Id annotation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Column(unique=true)
public String noticeTitle;
```

Relevant documentation:[@javax.persistence.Column](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Column.html#unique--).

Answer (score 0):

you can use xUtils->DBUtils
and add Annotation above flied

```
@Unique
private String name;
```